# Saving scores into a text file Java Eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I have created a game it has two players, I want to know how I can save both players scores into a text file which can then be reused when the application is opened again, I have been researching shared preferences but I am hitting a brick wall can any one help thanks.

Comment: Use a local database or the Google Play Services to store the scores online.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your problem. Try posting your Reading/Writing code snippet and also describe where your current solution fails

Comment: Shared preferences is very easy to use.But your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Create an instance of a class like this in your launcher activity.

```
public class SharedPrefs {
public static String hScore="H_SCORE";
public static final String myPref = "MY_PREF" ;
public BaseGameActivity activity;
private SharedPreferences shpref;
public SharedPrefs(BaseGameActivity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
    shpref = activity.getSharedPreferences(myPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!shpref.contains(hScore)){
        Editor editor = shpref.edit();
        editor.putString(hScore, "0");
        editor.commit();
    }

}
public void checkAndSetHscore(int score){
    if(score>Integer.parseInt(getHScore())){            
        Editor editor = shpref.edit();
        editor.putString(hScore, ""+score);
        editor.commit();        
    }
}
public String getHScore(){
    shpref = activity.getSharedPreferences(myPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return shpref.getString(hScore, "");        
}
```

}